Character fires TouchEnded event if another character intersects same character
When I try to detect character entering/exiting a specified container, it can toggle wrong events if another character intersects this character. How do I fix that?

This question is similar to: In Lua Roblox API, how does one debounce a player/character that runs into a box?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
